# xUnit Run a Test but don't fail the run if it fails

Tags: xunit, xunit.net

Is it possible using xUnit to run a test but to essentially only log the result rather than having any failures fail the whole test run?

Our use case is around long running re-factoring. We may have a test or tests that will continue to fail until the re-factoring is complete. We'd like to use the output of the test(s) to demonstrate progress being made on the re-factoring and then eventually when all the refactoring is complete use the test to enforce that we don't have any regressions.

So we'd need the test to either just log the result but not fail the test run or for it produce a warning or something similar rather than a failure.

Comment: wrap the test in a try/catch and then assert.ignore in the catch ? But really this is not standard practice for a reason

Comment: Thats fair, it is a bit of an unusual think to want to do.

Comment: In your build pipeline, graph how many tests fail, and don't allow it to increase.  You can't guarantee someone hasn't fixed one and broken another, but you can guarantee that it's not getting worse.